# Titanium facebook login/logout button not showing dialog

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I want to add facebook login button to my appcelerator titanium mobile app.
After following this doc : [Titanium facebook module](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Facebook)

I am able to display facebook login button :

```js
var fb = require('facebook');
fb.addEventListener('login', function(e) {
    if (e.success) {
        alert('login from uid: '+e.uid+', name: '+ JSON.parse(e.data).name);
        label.text = 'Logged In = ' + fb.loggedIn;
    }
    else if (e.cancelled) {
        // user cancelled
        alert('cancelled');
    }
    else {
        alert(e.error);
    }
});

fb.addEventListener('logout', function(e) {
    alert('Logged out');
});

fb.authorize();
$.win.open();
```

for the view :

```js
<Alloy>
 <Window id="win" class="container">
  <View id="fblogin" class="fblogin">
   <LoginButton id="fbLogin" module="facebook" />
  </View>
 </Window>
</Alloy>
```

But when i click on the facebook login button, it open a second window the following message : **Not Logged In: You are not logged in. Please login and try again.**

No login dialog is shown just this message and user cannot login either.

I just want to open login dialog and when success return to app with user infos.

Note : I also get notice from facebook as **given url is not allowed by the application configuration**.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Select a module vesion prior 5 (in my case 4.0.5) that solved the problem to me

greetings

Comment: Thank you, how to do that please?

Comment: on the tiapp.xml file at the module selection part, double click on Facebook module and the select combo should have * [latest], change it to a version prior the latest and try againg you App